# Trouble with knitting, object not found

Tags: r, knitr

I was trying to knit my document, but came across an error:

Error in eval (expr, envir, enclos) : object 'AVG' not found
Calls: ...withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

This was my code. I'm confused because I thought I defined AVG in the second line. Any ideas?

```
for (i in 1:30) 
 {AVG[i] <- mean(rnorm(100))
}
"SD" <- sd(AVG)
print(SD)
```

Comment: No, AVG is not defined in the second line. If you want AVG to be a vector to which you can assign values, try `AVG <- vector()` before the loop. You could also avoid the loop and use `replicate()` instead: `AVG <- replicate(30, mean(rnorm(100)))`

Comment: Aha, thank you! I'm very new to this, so thanks for explaining.